# (_, _, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void'

Tags: xcode, swift, alamofire

I imported Alamofire the way I used to successfully import it, and when I had this code, there comes an error:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, postEndPoint).responseJSON {(request, response, result) in
//Error: '(_, _, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void'

        guard let value = result.value else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }

        guard result.error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /posts/1")
            print(result.error)
            return
        }

        let post = JSON(value)

        print("The post is: " + post.description)
        if let title = post["title"].String {
            print("The title is: " + title)
        } else {
            print("Error parsing /posts/1")
        }
}
```

I didn't use CocoaPods for Alamofire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Alamofire 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md).

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, postEndPoint).responseJSON { response in
    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```

This is the new way of getting the JSON.

---

`response.result` is the new way of getting `result`.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, postEndPoint).responseJSON { response in
    guard let value = response.result.value else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        return
    }

    guard response.result.error == nil else {
        print("error calling GET on /posts/1")
        print(response.result.error)
        return
    }

    let post = JSON(value)

    print("The post is: " + post.description)
    if let title = post["title"].String {
        print("The title is: " + title)
    } else {
        print("Error parsing /posts/1")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I must declare the 'response' and 'result' constant?

Comment: @BrightFuture I don't understand your question. You should never need to specify their type, that is done automatically. The old request is `response.request`, the old response is `response.response`, and the old result is `response.result`.

Comment: Please see the updated code. If I replace the `(request, response, result)` with `request`, I will have multiple errors saying: use of unresolved identifier `result`, `JSON`, how should I solve this problem?