# How does "let JSON" work in Alamofire/Swift

Tags: json, swift, enums, closures, alamofire

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589635) I see that the proper Alamofire 2/Swift 2 syntax when dealing with a JSON response is:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
.responseJSON { request, response, result in
    switch result {
    case .Success(let JSON):
        print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

    case .Failure(let data, let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

        if let data = data {
            print("Response data: \(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)")
        }
    }
}
```

How and where is the `let JSON` defined? (From a Swift point of view.)

I see in a request extension that `ResponseSerializer` returns `.Success(JSON)` but why is the handler not defined like a usual function:

```
case .Success(JSON: AnyObject?) {
    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
}
```

or better yet:

```
case .Success(JSON: NSDictionary?) {
    print("Success with NSDictionary: \(JSON)")
}
```

Comment: Is not defined anywhere, that simply is the syntax for using enums with data inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is enum with cases `.Success`, `.Failure`. Enum cases in Swift can hold some value (by the way, that's how Optionals in Swift work, they are enums with two cases Some: which wraps a value and None). By calling `case .Success(let JSON):` in switch you assign this value to `JSON` constant and you can use it in case block. Type of this constant is automatically inferred.

For more information about it, check paragraph "Associated Values" in [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

Comment: So basically `result.value` is being set to `JSON`?

Comment: @boidkan Looks like it, and the type of result.value is `Value?` which I don't fully understand yet, but seems similar to the old `NSValue` wrapper(?).

Comment: You receive `result` as one of the arguments of the handler which is passed as an argument for `responseJSON` method. `result` is an enum and you can access the value which is associated with this enum with the syntax you asked about. You do not set anything there. Here https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Result.swift you can see that actually calling `result.value` does under the hood the same thing as in your question.