# How to return UID from user registration API

Tags: swift, rest, authentication, user-registration

How can I return the user ID from my Drupal 7 REST services after my IOS swift Xcode7 API registers a user to my site?  The console returns a status 200 (OK) but not the UID registered, which I will need for further functions. What further lines of code do I need to include here, or can I add as a separate API?

Here is my code:

```
 import UIKit
 import Foundation
 import Alamofire
 import SwiftyJSON

class submitVoteViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print("loaded page1")
}

@IBAction func register(sender: AnyObject) {

    // register user

    let voteEndpoint: String = "https://www.example.com/ios1/user/register.json"
    let newVote = ["account":["name":"example name", "mail":"examplemail@gmail.com", "pass":"examplepass", "status":1]]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, voteEndpoint, parameters: newVote, encoding: .JSON)
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            print(request)
            print (response)
            print (error)
    }
```

}

When i look it up, the Drupal site shows me the UID is 375 (blocked, though I had entered status 1 so that the user would be active?) . The console response is;

loaded page1
Optional( { URL: https://www.example.com/ios1/user/register.json })
Optional( { URL: https://www.example.com/ios1/user/register.json } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 16 Jul 2016 23:03:37 GMT";
    Expires = "Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10, max=200";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "DRUPAL_UID=0; expires=Fri, 15-Jul-2016 23:03:37 GMT; Max-Age=-86401; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure, DRUPAL_UID=-1; expires=Tue, 09-Aug-2016 02:36:57 GMT; Max-Age=1999999; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.9";
} })
nil

Comment: what is your `print (response)` output? it should be from there just get the value by key

Comment: hi cod3rite, thank you for the suggestion. I have added the console response above. I see in it that it notes ""Set-Cookie"=DRUPAL_UID=0", and then DRUPAL_UID=-1, but looking up the user in the drupal site shows the UID of 375, blocked, though I had entered status as 1 for active. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, i mean `print(response.result.value`) or `print(data)`

Comment: i added print(data) to the code. In addition to the same console message returned, it adds a lot of numbers (too many characters for me to add here in comment), starting with; Optional(<207b2266 6f726d5f 6572726f 7273223a 7b226e61 6d65223a 22546865 206e616d 65203c65 6d20636c 6173733d 5c22706c 61636568 6f6c6465 725c223e 61706934 3c2f656d 3e206973 20616c72 65616479 2074616b 656e2e22

Comment: PS when i added print(data) to the code, it now returns status 406

Comment: OK I got the status 406 unauthorized as I was trying the same user registration. I have updated the user registration to a new registration. I get the 200 status response, and this : } })
Optional(<207b2275 6964223a 22333738 222c2275 7269223a 22687474 70733a2f 2f777777 2e63696e 656d6d65 7273652e 636f6d2f 696f7331 2f757365 722f3337 38227d>)

Comment: just added my answer. what is the `print(response.result.value) ` ?

Comment: I'm getting a red alert error message 'value of type NSHTTPURLResponse?' has no member result' when I add the line print(response.result.value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the response from services,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2016 18:12:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1h mod_fcgid/2.3.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

{"uid":"3","uri":"http://drupal-7-43.dd/Api/v1/user/3"}
```

So the response object should have a uid attached to it.

H44f33z's answer is correct.

Comment: thank you H44f33z and Kyle, it worked.   confirming the working code is: 
   
                Alamofire.request(.POST, voteEndpoint, parameters: newVote, encoding: .JSON)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        
                        
                        if let JSON = response.result.value {
                            // JSON is your sever response
                            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                            
                            // you get the uid from this
                            let name = JSON["uid"] as! String

Comment: Hi Kyle and helpful people, I am using this same code in my Xcode but getting an error message on the line 'if let JSON = response.result.value', the error says 'value of type NSHTTPURL response? has no member 'result'. I've tried updating the Alamofire to 3.0, same error. I was finding this error coming up a lot before- am wondering if there is something about where the code is placed, or what could be bringing this? Would very much appreciate your thoughts.  I have Base64credentials added before the API.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the response using the `response.result` with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). your code will be as follow.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, voteEndpoint, parameters: newVote)
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
            case .Success(let value) :
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(value)
            print(swiftyJSON)

            // let say your output is {"uid": "1000", "name": "bob"}
            // you could get the uid from this
            let name = swiftyJSON["uid"].stringValue 
    }

}
```

Comment: hi cod3rite, thank you this sounds promising... I'm getting a red alert error message which says "value of type NSHTTPURLResponse?' has no member result' on  the line "if let JSON = response.result.value {".    Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much. I am now getting a red alert on "if let JSON = response.result.value {" saying 'value of tuple type '(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<AnyObject>)' (aka 'Optional<NSURLRequest., Optional<NSHUTTPURLResponse>, Result<AnyObject>)') has no member 'result'.   Must be close! Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry for late. could I know your alamofire version?

Comment: no worries and thank you. I do very much appreciate your help here. I'm using cocoa pods with Alamofire 2.0.2 and swiftyJSON

Comment: I see, maybe you can check the different here. hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114831/how-to-parse-json-response-from-alamofire-api-in-swift

Comment: @DimitriT I have edited the post. Please try and let me know if it works

Comment: thank you @SyafiqMastor. I enter that code exactly but it does not show 'Alamofire' in blue text as you had it, and on the line 'switch response result' I am getting a red alert 'Value of tuple type 'NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse Result<AnyObject>'(aka 'Optional'<NSURLRequest...

Comment: Have you use swiftyJSON as mentioned?

Comment: yes, I have at the top of the file:
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class submitVoteViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("loaded page1")
    }
    
 and then the code as I originally wrote, but with your replacement code from the line beginning 'Alamofire.request'...

Comment: I have updated my original post to include the code beforehand (including import Alamofire) to clarify and give context, in case it is of help.