# Putting JSON data into an array when using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to retrieve data from my site, I am using Alamofire, how can I put that data into an array that I can use to populate my table view?

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request("http://lytestech.ga/api/lytes/get_movies/").responseJSON { response in


            if let json = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
                let res = json as! NSDictionary
                let movies = res["movies"] as! NSArray
                // movieTitles = movies["movie_desc"]
                let movieTitles: [String] = movies["movietitile"] as! String
                print (movies)
                print (movieTitles)

            }


            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
            }
        }

    }
```

json data

```
JSON: {
    movies =     (
                {
            id = 66;
            "movie_desc" = "spiders bite";
            movietitile = spiderman;
        },
                {
            id = 64;
            "movie_desc" = horror;
            movietitile = mummy;
        }
    );
    status = ok;
}
(
        {
        id = 66;
        "movie_desc" = "spiders bite";
        movietitile = spiderman;
    },
        {
        id = 64;
        "movie_desc" = horror;
        movietitile = mummy;
    }
)
```

Comment: You can use SwiftyJSON for this: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114831/how-to-parse-json-response-from-alamofire-api-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: Do you know how to populate a tableview from  an array?

Comment: yes, i know how to do that @raki

Comment: then create an instance variable of array type, store movies data into that array and pass that array to the datasource methods of the tableview to populate it. @GideonLytes

Comment: I have managed to put it into an array,  the challenge am now facing is that the view actually populates/loads minus using the new contents of the array fetched! @raki

Answer (score 0):

Convert your response `Data` into `Dictionary`

```
let dictionary: Dictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: response.data) as! [String : Any]
```

Extract your `Array` from `Dictionary` , there is key name `movies`

```
 if let arryMovies1 = dictionary["movies"] as? [[String:Any]] {

        print (arryMovies1);

  // Now your have your Array 
  // You can Populate into UItableView
  // when your array is modified than you have to reload the tableData


       self.arryMovies=arryMovies1
      self.tableView.reloadData()

      }
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for populating in list view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "you_cell_identifre") as! UITableCell

                let dicMovie = self.arryMovies[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

                cell.lableTitle.text = dicMovie.value(forKey: "movietitile") as? String

             return cell
         }
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 var movies:[Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] = [] // Makes movies array global
 movies = res["movies"] // and tableview reload

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) ??
        UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

    cell.textLabel!.text = movies[indexPath.row]["movietitile"] as? String

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store movies in movies `NSArray`

```
var movies = NSArray()
```

After that in `cellForRowAt` method you can display data like this.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as! YouCustomCell

            let movieDetail = movies[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

            cell.lblMovieName.text = movieDetail.value(forKey: "movietitile") as? String
            return cell
        }
```

Note: - This is just code skeleton, you can use as per your custom cell and Outlets

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
func demo()
{
    let str  : String =  "http://lytestech.ga/api/lytes/get_movies/"
    let url =  NSURL(string:str)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    Alamofire.request(request)
        .responseString { response in
            switch (response.result) {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                let data = JSON.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                do {
                    let responseString = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    // print(responseString!)
                    self.movieName = []
                    self.desc = []
                    let arr = responseString!["movies"] as! NSArray
                    for j in 0..<arr.count{
                        let dic = arr[j] as! NSMutableDictionary
                        self.movieName.addObject(dic.valueForKey("movietitile")!)
                        self.desc.addObject(dic.valueForKey("movie_desc")!)
                    }
                    self.removeIndicator()
                    self.contactTable.reloadData()
                } catch _ as NSError {
                    //print(error)
                }
                break
            case .Failure:
                print("FAILURE")
                self.removeIndicator()
                break
            }
    }
}
```