# How to show Api response in tableview cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I am stuck in my code, I am trying show to API response tableview cell but i have not any idea how to fill data in array ,So not showing anything in my  tableviewcell. I am using custome cell and  Alamofire in swift. Please improve my mistake give me solution .

```
func Api_call()
{
    let url = URL(string: "https://dousic.com/api/radiolist")!
    let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)!
    // let fragment = components.fragment!
    print(components)

    let params = ["user_id":"16"  ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON {response in
         self.hideActivityIndicator()
        var err:Error?
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)


            let json = JSON(value)

            // returns nil if it's not an array
            if let resData = json["radioList"].arrayObject
            {
                self.array_RadioList = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }
              if self.array_RadioList.count > 0 {
                    self.tbl_home.reloadData()
                }

        case .failure(let error):
            err = error
            print(err ?? "error .....")
        }
    }

}`
```

Thanks for help .

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: I am new in swift so can you please help me to resolve my problem @ Moritz.

Comment: this is my Api response '{
    response =     {   code = 200; radioList =   ( {
                "genre_name" =   ( {
                        "genre_id" = 1;
                        "genre_name" = Country;
                    }  );
                "radio_des" = "Lee Brice - Love Like Crazy ";  "radio_fev" = 1;
                "radio_id" = 30;  "radio_img" "https://dousic.com/uploads/s48937q.png";
        "radio_tags" = ".977 Country";
                "radio_title" = "Lee Brice - Love Like Crazy";
               "radio_url"="http://7579.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/977_COUNTRY_SC"; },'

Comment: Please provide code for your tableview delegate methods, also check your response by printing self.array_RadioList after this line `self.array_RadioList = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]`

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell : homeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeCell")! as! homeCell
         var dict = array_RadioList[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
     cell.lbl_name?.text = dict["radio_title"] as? String
          return cell
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON response from Alamofire API in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114831/how-to-parse-json-response-from-alamofire-api-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Just create a radio list variable like this 

    var array_RadioList:[JSON]?

Get array from json like this    
-
    if let resData = json["response"]["radioList"].array {
                    self.array_RadioList = resData
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
and reload data.And get radio object in 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell? = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
        let radio:JSON? = array_RadioList?[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = radio?["radio_tags"].string
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Comment: self.array_RadioList = resData as! [[String:Any]] how to write this line it's getting error Cast from'[JSON] to unrelated type '[[String :Any]]' always fails

Comment: Why are you casting this with [String:Any]?.

Comment: Just create ---- var array_RadioList: [JSON]? and pass resData to array_RadioList

Comment: And use "let radio = array_RadioList?[indexPath.row]" in cellForRowAt for getting radio object.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array_RadioList! .count
    } give this error

Comment: Thanks you @Pradeep .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155329/discussion-between-pooja-srivastava-and-pardeep-bishnoi).

Answer (score 0):

If the API you're calling is well-made, you should use a get method, not a post.
Also, I tried to use "https://dousic.com/api/radiolist?user_id=16" but it return

```
{
    "response": {
        "code": "301",
        "error": "wrong url"
    }
}
```

These 2 things could be your problem, or it could be in your custom cells, or in you cellforrow method...
If you can show more code it would help.

---

**EDIT**

Try to use this version of the optional chaining :

```
if let resData = json["radioList"].arrayObject as? [[String:AnyObject] {
    self.array_RadioList = resData
    self.tbl_home.reloadData()
}
```

and try to debug it with breakpoints to see if the application goes everywhere you want and what are your variables at this time.

Comment: No i get my response .

Comment: How to use parameters in get method .

Comment: {
    response =     {
        code = 301;
        error = "wrong url";
    };
} getting this error after using .GET

Comment: do you know if you go in this : 
if self.array_RadioList.count > 0 {
self.tbl_home.reloadData()
}

Comment: Show me 0 element .@Damien Bannerot

Comment: (lldb) po array_RadioList
0 elements

(lldb) po array_RadioList.count
0

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your array_RadioList from Api_call(), try this

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : homeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeCell")! as! homeCell
    cell.lbl_name?.text = array_RadioList[indexPath.row]["radio_title"] as? String 
    return cell
 }`

and also check for numberOfRowsInSection function.

Comment: Nothing will be changed.

Comment: Then check if tableview reload data is getting called by using breakpoints inside your tableview functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return [self.array_RadioList].count;
}
```