# Swift 4 Parse JSON with Alamofire to get pain of key value

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

Please help me to parse this JSON structure. What i want to do is... get specific **id** and for this **id** get **category_image**.
I tried to use Alamofire, but for now nothing...
So basically what i want to get is **id** and related with this **id**, **category_image**.

i tried to parse this way, but i gues its wrong way...

```
Alamofire.request("http://хх.хх.ххх:хххх/api/v1/institution/get-all-institutions", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let objJson = response.result.value as! NSDictionary? {
                for element in objJson {
                    let data = element as! NSDictionary
                    if let array = data["data"] as! NSArray? {
                        for obj in array {
                            print(obj)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

**JSON:**

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "socials": {
            "vk": "https://vk.com/cafe_teplominsk",
            "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/teplo_cafe/",
            "facebook": "https://www.facebook.com/cafeteplominsk"
        },
        "short_title": "#тепло",
        "title": "Кафе #тепло",
        "latitude": "53.93820000",
        "longitude": "27.58520000",
        "image": "https://static.relax.by/images/common/catalog_round_logos/d3e4a58f89cdf9ebba2b6759a6e1fe08.jpg",
        "site": "http://cafeteplo.by/",
        "description": "Невозможно представить заведение с более теплой и радушной атмосферой.\r\n\r\nПомимо отличного сервиса и качественного обслуживания кафе #Тепло поразит Вас необыкновенным интерьером в стиле Прованс с абажурами и оригинальными декорациями.\r\n\r\nХорошо там, где #тепло!",
        "phone": "+375 29 639 22 22",
        "work_time": "С 09:00 до 23.00",
        "category": "Кафе",
        "category_image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/coffee@3x.png",
        "features": "{\"Wi-Fi\": \"Есть\", \"Залы\": \"Зал (85 мест) для некурящих\", \"Сайт\": \"cafeteplo.by\", \"Кухня\": \"Европейская, Итальянская\", \"Метро\": \"Академия наук\", \"Район\": \"Советский\", \"В меню\": \"Пицца, Обеденное меню, Завтраки, Морепродукты, Стейки, Доставка еды, Десерты, Салаты и холодные закуски\", \"Банкет\": \"До 16 чел.\", \"Музыка\": \"Тихая фоновая\", \"Курение\": \"Запрещено\", \"Описание\": \"на портале relax.by\", \"Парковка\": \"Есть\", \"Для детей\": \"Да\", \"Кинотеатры\": \"Октябрь\", \"Предоплата\": \"в размере 30%\", \"Средний счет\": \"$$\", \"Кондиционеры\": \"Есть\", \"Тип заведения\": \"Кафе\", \"способ оплаты\": \"Наличный расчет, Безналичный расчет, Оплата пластиковой картой\", \"Пицца на вынос\": \"Есть\", \"Разливное пиво\": \"Zlatý Bažant, Heineken, Ирландское, Бельгийское, Белорусское\", \"Количество мест\": \"85\", \"Торговые центры\": \"Европа\", \"Большая компания\": \"Да\", \"Дисконтные карты\": \"карта друга со скидкой 10%\", \"Популярные места\": \"парк Дружбы Народов (пл. Бангалор), Логойский тракт\", \"Быстро перекусить\": \"Да\", \"Закрытие заведения\": \"Да\", \"Национальная кухня\": \"Итальянская\", \"Романтический ужин\": \"Да\", \"Предварительный заказ\": \"существует\", \"Условия закрытия залов\": \"50 рублей на человека\", \"Оплата пластиковой картой\": \"Есть\", \"Банкет на открытом воздухе\": \"Нет\", \"Условия закрытия заведения\": \"обсуждается с менеджером\", \"Организационные возможности\": \"Банкетное обслуживание, Вечеринки, Выездное обслуживание, Деловые переговоры, День рождения, Конференция, Корпоративное обслуживание, Организация детских праздников, Презентации, Свадьба, Семинар\", \"Количество залов под мероприятия\": \"1\", \"Что клиент может принести с собой\": \"обсуждается при составлении предзаказа\", \"Владение персоналом иностранными языками\": \"Английский\"}",
        "address": "Минск, ул.Богдановича 138",
        "created_at": "20.07.2017 13:10:42",
        "updated_at": "29.05.2018 16:12:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "socials": {
            "vk": "https://vk.com/mustangcafe",
            "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/cafemustang.minsk/",
            "facebook": null
        },
        "short_title": "Мустанг",
        "title": "Мустанг",
        "latitude": "53.95360000",
        "longitude": "27.41060000",
        "image": null,
        "site": "https://vk.com/mustangcafe",
        "description": "«Мустанг» — загородное барбекю-кафе с 15-летней историей.  Приехать сюда стоит,  чтобы попробовать оригинальные блюда, приготовленные на огне, такие как сочные стейки, сибас на гриле, ребрышки BBQ, шашлык из баранины и многие другие.\r\n\r\nВ кафе «Мустанг» можно проводить различные семейные и корпоративные праздники, свадьбы и выездные регистрации. Максимальное количество гостей — 250 человек (с учетом летней террасы). Есть отдельное банкетное меню.\r\n\r\nЕсть три зала: основной с барной стойкой, VIP и банкетный. Летняя терраса представлена 6 отдельно стоящими беседками. А каждую пятницу и субботу в «Мустанге» проходят вечера живой музыки.",
        "phone": "+375 44 775 37 35",
        "work_time": "С 11:00 до 00:00",
        "category": "Кафе",
        "category_image": "http://95.46.99.250:9095/storage/photos/coffee@3x.png",
        "features": "{\"Wi-Fi\": \"Есть\", \"Залы\": \"Зал 1 (25 мест), Зал 2 (25 мест), Зал 3 (50 мест)\", \"Кухня\": \"Белорусская, Европейская\", \"В меню\": \"Шашлык, Обеденное меню, Выпечка, Стейки\", \"Банкет\": \"До 100 чел.\", \"Другое\": \"Бутылочное Чешское пиво\", \"Музыка\": \"Тихая фоновая, Живая музыка\", \"Курение\": \"Разрешено, есть зал для некурящих\", \"Парковка\": \"Есть\", \"Предоплата\": \"По договоренности\", \"Развлечения\": \"TV с большим экраном, Актёры, Живая музыка, Звёзды эстрады, Танцоры, Танцпол, Шоу-программа\", \"Кондиционеры\": \"Есть\", \"Тип заведения\": \"Кафе\", \"способ оплаты\": \"Наличный расчет, Безналичный расчет\", \"Летняя терраса\": \"Есть\", \"Популярные места\": \"Минское море\", \"Предварительный заказ\": \"Есть\", \"Оплата пластиковой картой\": \"Есть\", \"Банкет на открытом воздухе\": \"Да\", \"Организационные возможности\": \"Банкетное обслуживание, Вечеринки, Выездное обслуживание, Деловые переговоры, День рождения, Конференция, Корпоративное обслуживание, Организация детских праздников, Презентации, Свадьба, Семинар, Фуршет\", \"Количество залов под мероприятия\": \"3\", \"Что клиент может принести с собой\": \"Алкоголь, Кондитерские изделия, Фрукты\", \"Владение персоналом иностранными языками\": \"Английский, Итальянский\"}",
        "address": "Минский р-н, Ждановичский сельсовет, 12 км от трассы Р28 Минск-Молодечно",
        "created_at": "20.07.2017 13:10:42",
        "updated_at": "20.05.2018 20:21:30"
    },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON response from Alamofire API in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114831/how-to-parse-json-response-from-alamofire-api-in-swift)

Comment: Do **not** use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system. Use native types. And the syntax `as! Foo?` (**force** downcast an optional to an optional) is ridiculous. I wish the compiler threw an error. Optional / conditional downcast is `as? Foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , i created two arrays for storing Id and category_image like this `var AllIds = [Int]()
     var Allimages = [String]()`

```
  if let objJson = response.result.value as! [String: Any]? {
                for (key,value) in objJson {
                    print(key)
                    if let result2:[[String:Any]] = value as? [[String:Any]]{
                        for dict in result2 {

                            for (key,value) in dict {
                                if key == "id" {
                                    if let str: Int = value as? Int {
                                        self.AllTexts.append(str)
                                    }
                                }
                                if key == "category_image" {
                                    if let str1: String = value as? String {
                                        self.Allimages.append(str1)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Great! Its working for me! I have one more question... how i can relate id with image now?  like get image for this id

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if let array = data["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
      for obj in array {
            print(obj["id"],obj["category_image"])
       }
}
```

//

```
struct Root:Decodable {
  let  data: [InnerItem]
}
```

//

```
struct InnerItem:Decodable {
  let  id: Int
  let  categoryImage:String

  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case id , categoryImage = "category_image"
  }
}
```

//

```
do {
   let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: dataOfResponse)
   print(items.data)
}
catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: if let array = data["data"] as! [[String:Any]] mark as "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[[String : Any]]'"

Comment: it's **as?** instead of **as!**

Comment: one more fail at | let data = element as! NSDictionary
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)