# How to Extract JSON Response Values Coming From PHP Backend in Swift iOS

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, httpresponse

I uploaded an image using almofire and it is being uploaded to the correct path I require.

However, I need to get some of the responses that are in my PHP backend code into my swift such as the `filepath`.

An image to make my question more clear and precise about what I want to get from the `.responseJSON`

In the image below is my response from the PHP code, I want to get the value of the filepath in swift. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Here is my code:

PHP:

```
<?php

if (empty($_FILES["image"])) {
    $response = array("error" => "nodata");
}

else {
    $response['error'] = "NULL";
   
    $filename = uniqid() . ".jpg";
 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "../propertyImages/" . $filename)) {
   
        $response['status'] = "success";
        $response['filepath'] = "https://example.com/WebService/propertyImages/" . $filename;
        $response['filename'] = "".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

} else{
   
    $response['status'] = "Failure";
    $response['error']  = "".$_FILES["image"]["error"];
    $response['name']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["name"]; 
    $response['path']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $response['type']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $response['size']   = "".$_FILES["image"]["size"];
  }
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Swift Code:

```
 self.imageData = propImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
                ]

                    AF.upload(
                        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                            multipartFormData.append(self.imageData!, withName: "image" , fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    },
                        to:"https://example.com/WebService/api/uploadPropImage.php", method: .post , headers: headers)
                        .responseJSON { resp in
                            //let responseString: String = String(data: self.imageData!, encoding: .utf8)!
                            print(resp) //this prints all the responses from the PHP code, my problem is how do i get a specific response, such as the filepath only and so on?
            }
```

EDIT:

I tried some of the solutions, this one seems to be the one that will work but still gives an error reading

```
"No exact matches in call to class method 'jsonObject'"
```

Updated code:

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in                           multipartFormData.append(self.imageData!, withName: "image" , fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")},                      to:"https://example.com/WebService/api/uploadPropImage.php", method: .post , headers: headers).responseJSON {
   result in
                        
 do{
   if let jsonResults = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: result, options: []) as? [String: Any] { //error in this line
 let filePath = jsonResults["filepath"] as? String 
                            }
          }catch{
         print("ERROR")
     }
```

Comment: try print(rep.filepath)

Comment: @AqibJaved this is what i get an error that says, `Value of type 'AFDataResponse<Any>' (aka 'DataResponse<Any, AFError>') has no member 'filepath'`

Comment: @AqibJaved and how can i do that?

Comment: It's already decoded. You need to use a switch on `resp`, in case of success, you can cast the value as `[String: Any]`, and retrieve the value...

Comment: @Larme can you please give a detailed answer/example?

Comment: You need to understand `Result`, see the doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/writing_failable_asynchronous_apis It's really commonly used. Then, the value is a `Any`, but can be casted as `[String: Any]`, so it's just a dictionary afterwards

Comment: @Larme you cant post an answer please? i am getting errors for everything i try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON response from Alamofire API in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114831/how-to-parse-json-response-from-alamofire-api-in-swift)

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin no, as you can see from my code i am using a different way. i am using `AF.upload` not `Almofire.request.` and both are a bit different in how to handle the parsing of json and retrieving the data

Comment: `result` is not a `Data`, that's why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just decode your response:

```
if let jsonResults = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
    let filePath = jsonResults["filepath"] as? String // here is your value
}
```

Comment: Why use `JSONSerialization` if while using `.responseJSON`, there was already a call to `JSONSerialization`? That's doing twice the job...

Answer (score -1):

The value of the `responseJSON` block, is a `Result`. It's a basic concept used frequently, so you need to learn how do handle it. Common practice is then to use a `switch`.

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-type": "multipart/form-data"]

AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(self.imageData!, withName: "image" , fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                             },
                              to:"https://example.com/WebService/api/uploadPropImage.php", method: .post , headers: headers)
   .responseJSON { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let json):
            guard let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] else { print("Response JSON is not a dictionary"); return }
            guard let filePath = json["filePath"] as? String else { print("filePath key is not present in "\(json)" or is not a String");  return }
            print("Filepath: \(filePath)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

}

Now, it might be better to use a `Codable` struct to parse your response and call `responseDecodable()` instead of using `responseJSON()` which will use `JSONSerialization`, method which is by the way deprecated and will be removed in next Alamofire major release.